# Android : getInputStream() results in an EOFException

Tags: java, android, http, exception

I have a java tcp server which writes to the output stream:

```
String hello = "hello";
OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
byte [] outputBuffer = hello.getBytes();
os.write(outputBuffer);
```

My Android app tries to read from input stream:

```
URL url = new URL("<ip:port>");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

It ends with an exception:

> java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection
>   
> (...)
>   Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=5 content=68656c6c6f

As we can see, the message is read correctly (size=5 content=68656c6c6f is byte equivalent of "hello"). I tried to add a new line at the end of byte array, but then I ended up with:

> java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: hello

What should I do ?

Comment: read https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-io-eofexception-how-to-solve-eofexception/

Comment: I used code from official documentation of Android https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html So I believe it is not a problem of implementation

Comment: `String protocol = "http";
            String host = "www.java2novice.com";
            int port = 80;
            String path = "/java_thread_examples/";
            URL url = new URL(protocol, host, port, path);`

Comment: please add `urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);`

Comment: When I connect to a website there is no exception. So I am pretty sure, the problem is on the TCP Server side. I probably need to add something when writing to the output stream...

Comment: "If the HTTP response indicates that an error occurred, getInputStream() will throw an IOException. Use getErrorStream() to read the error response"
when I use it and than print with Log.i, I get something like java.io.BufferedInputStream@58c56b0
Furthermore, urlConnection.getHeaderFields(); is empty